# How can I hide CPLEX's output in AMPL?

Tags: logging, output, solver, cplex, ampl

I want to hide messages like

> CPLEX 12.5.1.0: integer infeasible.
>  319 MIP simplex
>   iterations
>  0 branch-and-bound nodes
>  No basis.

I don't mind hiding successful messages or not, but I don't want unsuccessful messages.

I have tried

- `option cplex_options 'wantsol=8';`
- `option cplex_options 'logfile=rubbishFile.txt'`;
- `option cplex_options 'tunedisplay=0';`
- `option cplex_options 'incompat=0';`

But don't work.

Comment: I believe that message is actually coming from AMPL. The solver returns a string to the AMPL environment and it is the AMPL environment printing it. I don't know (yet) how to disable it... but it pretty much explains why you couldn't switch it off in CPLEX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that those lines are actually printed by the AMPL environment. Depending on what you want, please try these after suppressing all output from CPLEX:

- `option cplex_options 'outlev=0';` (this should quiet CPLEX) and
- `option solver_msg 0;` or
- `solve >rubbishFile.txt;`

Hope this helps.